# Is a Hölder continuous function differentiable almost everywhere?

Tags: analysis, derivatives, holder-spaces

As per the title. I know that a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable almost everywhere (see the [Rademacher Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem)). I was wondering if something similar was true for Hölder continuous functions.

Comment: For each $s < 1,$ there are nowhere differentiable continuous functions that are Hölder continuous with Hölder exponent $s.$ I'm pretty sure this was known by the 1890s (at least), but off-hand I don't know any really old specific references. A very strong result is Theorem 2.1 on p. 45 of [*On continuous functions with no unilateral derivatives*](http://www.numdam.org/item/AIF_1988__38_2_43_0/) by Masayoshi Hata (1988), which is freely available on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is Hölder continuous but differentiable nowhere.